# Puppeteer Div Tag null values

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, puppeteer

Trying to scrape asins from an Amazon search. they are in a div tag like below.

Example: <div data-asin="B007Q13M2Y"

Currently my code does return some , but mostly null's. Is there something i missing here?

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');



(async () => {

const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false, 
   
  });

const page = await browser.newPage();

var url = await page.goto('https://www.amazon.co.uk/s?k=TAKPART+Brass+Diff+Filler+Plug+Kit+Compatible+for+Discovery+2+Td5+%26+V8&crid=SCY3QG71TBS9&sprefix=takpart+brass+diff+filler+plug+kit+compatible+for+discovery+2+td5+%26+v8%2Caps%2C77&ref=nb_sb_noss#');






 const data = await page.evaluate(() => 
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".s-main-slot.s-result-list.s-search-results.sg- 
row")).map(d => d.getAttribute("data-asin"))
)


console.log(data)




})()
```

Output:
'',           null,         null,         null, null,
null,         null,         null,         null, null,
null,         null,         null,         null, null,
null,         null,         null,         null, null,
null,         '',           null,         null, null,
null,         'B07957YMTG', null,         null, null,
null,         null,         null,         null, null,
null,         null,         null,         null, null,
null,         null,         null,         null, null,
null,         null,         null,         null, null,
null,         null,         null,         null, null,
'B07SJGJVXR', null,         null,         null, null,
null,         null,         null,         null, null,
null,         null,         null,         null, null,
null,         null,         null,         null, null,
null,         null,         null,         null, null,
null,         null,         null,         null, null,
null,         null,         null,         null, null,
null,         null,         'B07WS9VMX6', null, null,
null,         null,         null,         null, null,
... 673 more items

Comment: maybe its ajax loaded

Comment: You can use: `[...document.querySelectorAll('[data-component-type="s-search-result"]')].map(el => el.dataset.asin)` to get all asin numbers from the search results.

Comment: HI, could you an add answer with snippet please